# parallel job processing with Azure Service Bus Queues

Tags: python, parallel-processing, message-queue, azureservicebus, asyncapi

I have an Azure Service Bus queue with Rest API requests for Database ingestion jobs.

For this, I have a requirement to create task workers to complete each job asynchronously as given in the below diagram.[image]

I want to process these messages in parallel. Will Celery work for this? Is there any suggestion on what I can choose to complete this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per the above mentioned information, you can follow this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779207/processing-messages-in-parallel-in-azure-service-bus) for your requirement.

I think Celery is a option that also works, as it is distributed task queue and an open source asynchronous task queue or job queue which is based on distributed message passing. Please refer this [link](https://www.zymergen.com/blog/technology/building-a-parallel-task-api-with-celery/).